# Is it possible to connect to device using ADB through serial port?

Tags: android, android-framework

I am now connecting my development device through ethernet because the usb port hasn't been enabled. But every time i restart some thread the connection is disconnected and dispatching a  app to device is also very slow. So i doubt is it possible to using serial port to connect?
thanks

Comment: Yes, i am able to connect over wifi. But the speed really can't satisfy me.

Comment: I found a very interesting device which can convert serial to usb. But  cost about 35$....http://www.xdevelop.at/